# Link terraform directories to centralised variables.tf file

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm working on Azure with Terraform. I want to build my code in such a way that it should be modular enough to use one variable.tf file which should be accessible from all directories (directories will have specific VM code). Let's say I have a `common_variable.tf` file and some directories like db_servers, fe_servers, be_servers etc. The code inside these directories will use the common_variable.tf file which is placed one level up from all directories. Currently, my setup is throwing errors as it is not finding the variables in the same directory. How can I link it up ?

ERROR:

```
$ terraform init
Initializing modules...
- module.frontend_deploy
- module.network
Error getting plugins: module root: 
  module frontend_deploy.root: 17 error(s) occurred:

* resource 'azurerm_storage_account.storage' config: unknown variable referenced: 'location'. define it with 'variable' blocks
* resource 'azurerm_storage_account.storage' config: unknown variable referenced: 'dns_name'. define it with 'variable' blocks
* resource 'azurerm_network_interface.nic' config: unknown variable referenced: 'location'. define it with 'variable' blocks
* resource 'azurerm_public_ip.external_lb_pip' config: unknown variable referenced: 'location'. define it with 'variable' blocks
* resource 'azurerm_virtual_machine.external_nginx' config: unknown variable referenced: 'location'. define it with 'variable' blocks
* resource 'azurerm_lb.lb' config: unknown variable referenced: 'location'. define it with 'variable' blocks
* resource 'azurerm_lb_rule.lb_rule' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg' referenced in variable azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg.name
* resource 'azurerm_virtual_machine.external_nginx' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg' referenced in variable azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg.name
* resource 'azurerm_virtual_machine.external_nginx' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_availability_set.external_nginx' referenced in variable azurerm_availability_set.external_nginx.id
* resource 'azurerm_lb.lb' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg' referenced in variable azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg.name
* resource 'azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend_pool' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg' referenced in variable azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg.name
* resource 'azurerm_lb_probe.lb_probe' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg' referenced in variable azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg.name
* output 'vm_fqdn': unknown resource 'azurerm_public_ip.lbpip' referenced in variable azurerm_public_ip.lbpip.fqdn
* resource 'azurerm_storage_account.storage' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg' referenced in variable azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg.name
* resource 'azurerm_network_interface.nic' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_subnet.subnet' referenced in variable azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
* resource 'azurerm_network_interface.nic' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg' referenced in variable azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg.name
* resource 'azurerm_public_ip.external_lb_pip' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg' referenced in variable azurerm_resource_group.wmic_rg.name
```

Comment: Why not just symlink it across?

Answer (score 3):

For `init` commands you can use the [-backend-config](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html) option to configure backends such as `azurerm`.

You can provide single values:

```
terraform init -backend-config="storage_account_name=abcd1234"
```

Or a path to a file containing backend config values:

```
terraform init -backend-config=../shared_config.tfvars
```

For `plan` or `apply` commands you can use the [-var-file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#var-file-foo) option to specify a file that contains your variables:

```
terraform plan -var-file=../common_variable.tf
```

Comment: I'm not looking for only init. Moreover, I want all my configuration to be modular. For example, db servers, app servers etc to be in different directories and common resources one level up. Also I have two var.tf files, one having server specific values and the other has common resource values. Now, if I run terraform (init, plan,apply) from the root directory it should call vm specific modules as well as common resources like network, resource groups etc. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: You will get better help by asking smaller, more specific questions. Here you are asking how to reference a single variable file from many places, which I believe I have answered.